# How to add double underline to label Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have some text and to some words I want to add the effect of double underlining.

```
<Label Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."/>
```

I tried to use BoxView in FlexLayout with a label, but because of this, there is a word wrap problem.

```
<FlexLayout JustifyContent="Start" AlignContent="Start" AlignItems="Start" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Wrap="Wrap" >
    <Label Text="Lorem " FontAttributes="Italic"/>
    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
        <Label Text="ipsum" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
        <BoxView WidthRequest="2" BackgroundColor="#747474" Color="#747474" HeightRequest="0.5"/>
        <BoxView WidthRequest="2" BackgroundColor="#747474" Color="#747474" Margin="0,2,0,0" HeightRequest="0.5"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Label Text=" dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." FontAttributes="Italic"/>
</FlexLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question should also contain "what you've tried". Would you mind to share it with us?

Comment: I have copy-pasted your exact code and it look good - both on Android and on iOS. Can you try to put it into an empty page, in order to see if the issue is with the FlexLayout, or something else in the code.

Comment: @MihailDuchev I use FlexLayout to line up the text.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Custom Renderer** and implement it in specific platforms.

In addition , double underline is available in iOS in default . But in Android , it is unavailable .

#### in iOS

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

using App34.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Label),typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]

namespace App34.iOS
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer:LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                var content = Control.Text;

                UIStringAttributes attributes = new UIStringAttributes() { UnderlineStyle = NSUnderlineStyle.Double,UnderlineColor=UIColor.Red };

                NSMutableAttributedString str = new NSMutableAttributedString(content, attributes);

                Control.AttributedText = str;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

#### in Android

The style is for single underline .

```
using Android.Content;

using Android.Widget;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

using App34.Droid;
using Android.Text;


[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Label), typeof(MyLabelRenderer))]
namespace App34.Droid
{
    public class MyLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        public MyLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {

               Control.SetText(Html.FromHtml("<u>" + Control.Text +"</u>",FromHtmlOptions.ModeLegacy),TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I need a double underscore exactly on android

Comment: You could use the plugin https://github.com/matteobortolazzo/HtmlLabelPlugin .